How to label grid cells in Arcgis Pro?
I was using ArcMap and now switched to ArcGis Pro. I had a shapefile of an area with an overlayed numbered grid. The grid cells were numbered starting from 1. After I input the layer in ArcGISPro, the grid now has the cells numbered starting from zero. How do I change it to starting from 1? Also, it shows the last cell number as 388. That should mean the grid now has 389 cells since the numbering starts from zero. But it should have 390 cells, as I saw in ArcMap. How do I solve this issue? As I am sure is apparent already, I am a complete novice when it comes to GIS softwares. Any help is appreciated.Thanks.
I tried loading the ArcMap layer a second time. I was expecting (and need) the grid cells to be numbered starting from 1 and not zero.
